# How to disable Gemfire DEFAULT pool creation in java client

Tags: java, pool, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

We are having an application which connects to Gemfire cluster for data.
We were connecting to `Gemfire 8` server using `gemfire-7.x.jar`.
Now our server is upgraded to `Gemfire 9` and we were asked to upgrade to `gemfire-8.2.x.jar` as the older ones are not compatible with our internal API jars.

A new issue started cropping up where gemfire default pool was getting created and it was trying to connect to `localhost:40404` where no cluster is available and hence was throwing an exception continuously. We found later that even in earlier versions, the pool was getting created but it wasn't throwing the exception as the same exception was logged at `fine` level which was disabled in our case whereas the same exception is now logged at `warn` level which is enabled for us.

We want to disable the default pool creation altogether through some configuration. Is it possible? I have seen the answers [here](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Default-Pool-Is-Always-Created-While-Configuring-A-GemFire-Client-Cache-Using-Java-APIs) but I want to disable the pool by configuration and not workarounds as suggested in the said post.

Comment: You might want to follow [GEODE-7200](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-7200).